# Why can't I edit my comment at a later point?

Tags: support, comments, editing

I recently went to edit a comment of mine, but wasn't able to. Shouldn't this be something everyone can do all the time - edit one's own comments without regard to a timeframe of when the comment was posted?

Comment: Would you also have a revision history for every comment?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/should-we-be-allowed-to-edit-comments

Comment: My apologies I am not a user of the other stack exchange sites so didn't notice this was asked already

Comment: @Earl No apology necessary. This is a perfectly valid question for MY Meta. The reference to a similar question on big Meta is useful for answering it here.

Comment: then why the down vote? I know it wasn't you. I think my question is a valid point as it would improve the site as a whole.

Comment: @Earl [Voting is different on Meta.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) Although this post isn't tagged [meta-tag:feature-request], it's possible that someone who disagreed with your proposed change downvoted on that basis, not as a comment on the quality or usefulness of your post.

Comment: Short version: that’s not how SE works. :)